# Can't Call Javascript Function in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, function, oop, jasmine

I'm new at Javascript, starting for the first time.  I am trying to use Jasmine to test objects and their methods.  I have the following code:

```
function Monkey(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.goteam = new function () {
        return x;
    };
}

describe("Cool", function () {
    it("should work", function () {
        var monkey = new Monkey(1, 2);
        var value = monkey.goteam();
        expect(value).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

The test Cool it should work gives me "[object Object] is not a function on the line value = monkey.goteam();  I have spent an hour reading tutorials and searching, but have come up dry no matter what I try.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `goteam` should just be a function, not `new function() ...` Pro tip: just try stuff out in the console before bothering to write a test; it excludes an entire class of issues. Creating a `new Monkey(...)` and looking at it would have helped clue you in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.goTeam` should be declared as a `function`, not a `new function`. The `new` keyword is not necessary here.